# New - Message: Declaration of Admin::delete($id = '') should be compatible with Core::delete($tbl, $database, $param, $id)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Severity: Warning

Message: Declaration of Admin::delete($id = '') should be compatible with Core::delete($tbl, $database, $param, $id)

Filename: controllers/admin.php

```
Controller Admin:

   function delete($id='')
{
    core::delete('admin','gammu','ID',$id);
    redirect('admin');
}

Core_Model:

function delete($tbl,$database,$param,$id)
{
    $this->model->delete($tbl,$database,$param,$id);
}
```

Comment: is this a mistake copying the code of your question or is it a typo: `}}` ?

Comment: error copying code here